# Vim suggestions for search commands / and?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have search suggestions for vim while typing in ? or / command?
Im looking something like... aka neocomplete, fuzzyfinder... see the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After typing `/`, you can press `<C-f>` to open the command-line window. In it, you can select / search for previous search patterns, edit them (just like in a normal buffer), and use the current one via `<Enter>`. You can also directly enter this mode via `q/`. To recall a previously used search, `<Up>` is quicker, though.

There are plugins that allow to complete words from the open buffer(s) into command-line mode. I use [CmdlineComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222).

Comment: Ah of course ... i'm rush headed i will make bindings for command like... q/:v/<mySting>/d ... also you are the man :D